# hive compute stats for columns on a partition table fails

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am trying to compute stats for my table in hive which is partitioned. I am running the following code

`hive --hiveconf hive.root.logger=DRFA --hiveconf hive.log.dir=./logs --hiveconf hive.log.level=ERROR -e "ANALYZE TABLE database.tablename PARTITION(Partition1, Partition2, Partition3, Partition4) COMPUTE STATISTICS FOR COLUMNS;"`

I keep getting the following error:

```
Cannot get table tablename 
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ColumnStatsTask
```

The hive version is Hive 2.3.7

The error in the log looks as follows:

```
2020-11-11T17:33:06,905 ERROR [Tez session start thread] tez.TezSessionState: Failed to start Tez session
java.io.IOException: java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState.startSessionAndContainers(TezSessionState.java:398) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState.access$000(TezSessionState.java:87) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState$1.call(TezSessionState.java:330) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState$1.call(TezSessionState.java:326) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_265]
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
        at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
        at org.apache.tez.client.TezClient.waitTillReady(TezClient.java:1020) ~[tez-api-0.9.2.jar:0.9.2]
        at org.apache.tez.client.TezClient.waitTillReady(TezClient.java:982) ~[tez-api-0.9.2.jar:0.9.2]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.tez.TezSessionState.startSessionAndContainers(TezSessionState.java:396) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        ... 5 more
2020-11-11T17:40:20,117 ERROR [1870388b-f548-4ede-a12b-191e21f34b3e main] metadata.Hive: Table tablename not found: default.tablename table not found
2020-11-11T17:40:20,129 ERROR [1870388b-f548-4ede-a12b-191e21f34b3e main] exec.StatsTask: Cannot get table tablename 
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.InvalidTableException: Table not found tablename 
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:1279) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:1230) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getTable(Hive.java:1217) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.StatsTask.execute(StatsTask.java:128) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:199) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:100) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:2184) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1839) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1526) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1237) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1227) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:233) ~[hive-cli-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:184) ~[hive-cli-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:403) ~[hive-cli-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:336) ~[hive-cli-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:787) ~[hive-cli-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759) ~[hive-cli-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:686) ~[hive-cli-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:244) ~[hadoop-common-2.10.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:158) ~[hadoop-common-2.10.0.jar:?]
2020-11-11T17:40:20,129 ERROR [1870388b-f548-4ede-a12b-191e21f34b3e main] exec.Task: Cannot get table tablename.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.InvalidTableException: Table not found tablename

2020-11-11T17:40:27,436 ERROR [1870388b-f548-4ede-a12b-191e21f34b3e main] exec.ColumnStatsTask: Failed to run column stats task
org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.setPartitionColumnStatistics(Hive.java:3781) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ColumnStatsTask.persistColumnStats(ColumnStatsTask.java:420) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ColumnStatsTask.execute(ColumnStatsTask.java:431) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.Task.executeTask(Task.java:199) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.TaskRunner.runSequential(TaskRunner.java:100) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.launchTask(Driver.java:2184) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.execute(Driver.java:1839) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1526) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1237) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1227) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:233) ~[hive-cli-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:184) ~[hive-cli-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:403) ~[hive-cli-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:336) ~[hive-cli-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:787) ~[hive-cli-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:759) ~[hive-cli-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:686) ~[hive-cli-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:244) ~[hadoop-common-2.10.0.jar:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:158) ~[hadoop-common-2.10.0.jar:?]
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:77) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_set_aggr_stats_for(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:3592) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.set_aggr_stats_for(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:3579) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.setPartitionColumnStatistics(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:1678) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.setPartitionColumnStatistics(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:355) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.invoke(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:173) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.setPartitionColumnStatistics(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_265]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient$SynchronizedHandler.invoke(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:2336) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy39.setPartitionColumnStatistics(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.setPartitionColumnStatistics(Hive.java:3778) ~[hive-exec-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
        ... 22 more
```

I am not sure why its complaining about the table missing when I am able to compute stats normally without the "for columns"

Any help would be much appreciated as I am pulling my hair out on this one.

Thanks

Comment: maybe it can help you. https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/ANALYZE-table-COMPUTE-STATISTICS-for-COLUMNS-fails-for/ta-p/246276